# Kentico Creating Page based on existing Page Type gives error

Tags: kentico

and thank you. I am following the Kentico 13 tutorial and I am facing the next error when I am trying to create a new page based on a page type that has page builder available:

"An error occurred while attempting to retrieve page templates. Contact your system administrator and check that the page builder feature is registered correctly in the MVC project."

I have registered page builder by doing `features.UsePageBuilder()` in the configuration of the project so I am not sure what I have wrong here. Thank you again if someone can help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the suggestions from this [thread](https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/version-12-sp-mvc-page-tab-shows-404-error) on the same error?